# Selenium, run firefox without displaying the windows on windows

Tags: windows, selenium, firefox

I have a selenium java script, but i want to test multiple execution of this script at the same time in different instance of firefox. What is bothering me is that the script always open a new page. So i f i want to execute this script with multiple user, it could be a little bit messy. I was looking for a way to execute a selenium script without any display of the window, most of the answer comes to  xfvb on GNU/linux distribution, but i'm on windows.
I found this google groups : [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/b-_8zzUiF38).
And an user said that i could do the same on windows by running firefox as a service. I don't anything about on the internet.
Someone know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google groups reference is way to old (almost 5 years) not sure if that works today...
You can use headless browser such as HTMLunit and should use htmlunitdriver implementation to run tests HTMLunit browser.

Comment: I did not notice the date, indeed windows removed this option.
When you are speaking about HTMLunit driver are you refering to the HTLMunit software ? Or are you talking about the HtmlUnitdriver implementation from selenium ?

Comment: yes, I mean htmlunitdriver implementation of Selenium, it can help to solve your purpose....